# What is the correct way to generate AES-CBC-192 with CryptoJS?

Tags: javascript, cryptography, aes, cryptojs, pbkdf2

I arrived at the following code and would like to know if this is a correct and secure way to generate an AES-CBC-192 cipher with CryptoJS:

Original Question Code:

```js
let encrypt = (text,key) => {


    let salt = "M@Tr05K@";

    let iv = CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.random(16);

    let key_to_bits = CryptoJS.PBKDF2(key,salt,{keySize: 192/8, iterations:30000});

    return CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(text,key,{iv:iv}).toString();


}

encrypt("Lorem ipsum...","¿MinhaSenha?>Segur@?");
```

Code with suggested changes:

```
let encrypt = (text, key) => {
  let salt = CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.random(16);
  let iv = CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.random(16);
  let key_to_bits = CryptoJS.PBKDF2(key, salt, {
    keySize: 192 / 32,
    iterations: 30000
  });

  return {result : CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(text, key_to_bits, {
    iv: iv
  }).toString(),
  salt:CryptoJS.enc.Hex.stringify(salt),
  iv:CryptoJS.enc.Hex.stringify(iv)
};
}

encrypt("Lorem ipsum...", "¿MinhaSenha?>Segur@?");
```

Thanks for listening :)

Comment: why not use the bulit in crypro instead of a slower non-official, and externally updated library?

Comment: I didn't know this existed...

Comment: _... would like to know if this is a correct and secure way..._ No, because the key size must be specified in words (4 bytes), i.e. `192/32` for a 192 bits key. Furthermore, a random salt must be used analogous to the IV. Salt and IV are not secret and have to be passed along with the ciphertext to the decrypting side (typically concatenated).

Comment: Also, of course, in `encrypt()` you have to pass `key_to_bits` and not `key`. But this is probably just a typo.

Comment: First, thanks everyone for your help... I made some bow changes with what I was told... So as it is now... would it be safe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here one i just finished for AES-CBC-256 from a password using PBKdf2, this is using the Web crypto api https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Crypto_API

not what you are looking for exactly but it might help with direction, remove importKey from below and read up on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SubtleCrypto/generateKey

```
function generateKey(passwd, iterations) {

  var encoder = new TextEncoder('utf-8');
  var passphraseKey = encoder.encode(passwd);
  var saltBuffer = encoder.encode("carthage");

  crypto.subtle.importKey(
    'raw',
    passphraseKey,
    {name: 'PBKDF2'},
    false,
    ['deriveBits', 'deriveKey']
  ).then(function(key) {
//    console.log(key);
    return window.crypto.subtle.deriveKey(
    { "name": 'PBKDF2',
      "salt": saltBuffer,
      "iterations": iterations,
      "hash": 'SHA-256'
    },
    key,
    { "name": 'AES-CBC',
      "length": 256
    },
    true,
    [ "encrypt", "decrypt" ]
  )
  }).then(function (webKey) {
//    console.log(webKey);
    return crypto.subtle.exportKey("raw", webKey);
  }).then(function (buffer) {
//    console.log(buffer);
//    console.log(saltBuffer);
    console.log("Private Key = " + buf2hex(buffer));
    console.log("Salt = " + bytesToHexString(saltBuffer));
  });


}


function buf2hex(buffer) { // buffer is an ArrayBuffer
  return Array.prototype.map.call(new Uint8Array(buffer), x => ('00' + x.toString(16)).slice(-2)).join('');
}

function bytesToHexString(byteArray) {
  return Array.prototype.map.call(byteArray, function(byte) {
    return ('0' + (byte & 0xFF).toString(16)).slice(-2);
  }).join('');
}
```